# For loop and conditions on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

Suppose I have the following list:

```
l = ['AF_','LT_']
```

and the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5],'col2':['AF_123_PX','OX','AF','BX','LT_123']})

   col1       col2
0     1  AF_123_PX
1     2         OX
2     3         AF
3     4         BX
4     5     LT_123
```

Now I would like to iterate over the values of `col2`, if I see the elements of `l` I would separate it and impute them to the new columns and if not I assign global. The result should look like the following:

```
   col1       col2    col3    col4
0     1  AF_123_PX      AF  123_PX
1     2         OX  Global      OX
2     3         AF  Global      AF
3     4         BX  Global      BX
4     5     LT_123      LT     123
```

As you can see `AF_` and `LT_` exist on the list `l`. I wrote the following:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if df['col2'].str.contains(l):
        df['col3'] == l
        df['col4'] == df.col2.str.split("_", n=1).str[1]
    else: 
        df['col3'] == 'Global'
        df['col4'] == df['col2']
```

which didn't work, I wonder where am I making mistake?

Comment: You should always say **why** it didn't work. Was there an error or did it just give the wrong output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
l = ['AF_','LT_']
#your list
c=df['col2'].str.contains(f'({"|".join(l)})')
#checking if any element inside your list is present in col2 or not
```

Finally:

```
df.loc[~c,'col2']='Global_'+df.loc[~c,'col2']
#adding 'Global_' to col2 where the condition c failed
df[['col3','col4']]=df['col2'].str.split('_',1,expand=True)
#Finally spliting the columns and assigning it to df
```

output of `df`:

```
  col1  col2       col3     col4
0   1   AF_123_PX   AF      123_PX
1   2   Global_OX   Global  OX
2   3   Global_AF   Global  AF
3   4   Global_BX   Global  BX
4   5   LT_123      LT      123
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advise normally against creating new columns, because of cases when a string would be splitted into more than only 2 parts, then you could store it like this:

```
df['col3'] = df['col2'].str.split('({})'.format('|'.join(l))).map(lambda x: [y for y in x if y != ''])

   col1       col2           col3
0     1  AF_123_PX  [AF_, 123_PX]
1     2         OX           [OX]
2     3         AF           [AF]
3     4         BX           [BX]
4     5     LT_123     [LT_, 123]
```

That said, you can achive your expected output like this:

```
df[['col3', 'col4']] = df['col2'].str.split('({})'.format('|'.join(l)), expand = True).drop(0,axis=1)
df['col3'] = df['col3'].fillna('Global')
df.loc[df['col4'].isna(), 'col4'] = df.loc[df['col4'].isna(), 'col2']

   col1       col2    col3    col4
0     1  AF_123_PX     AF_  123_PX
1     2         OX  Global      OX
2     3         AF  Global      AF
3     4         BX  Global      BX
4     5     LT_123     LT_     123
```